# How to terminate running application in Eclipse kepler?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, terminate

I am developing gui and I want to terminate VM by key binding but not by clicking on red button in console.

It would be best if someone tell me how to relaunch application in eclipse kepler?

I tried to assign key bindings to Terminate option (when - In Windows) but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys

Find `Terminate`, and set your key binding.

You also need to change the `When` to `Editing Java Source`.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work. I found Terminate and changed its When from Debugging to Editing Java Source. Then when running app I clicked on java class pressed Ctrl+F2 and nothing happened

Comment: Make sure that when you press the key binding, your cursor is inside of the Java editing window.

Comment: Yes, so it is . I also tried to copy Terminate command and assign another key binding but it doesn't work too.